# What is the graph of $r \cos \theta = 3$?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

What is the graph of $r \cos \theta = 3$?

I don't get why there is a $\cos \theta$ in the side of $r$, even if I divide both sides by $\cos \theta$, the right side will be $3/\cos \theta$, which makes no sense. What is the graph of this equation?

Comment: Always remember the key points of polar coordinates: $$x = r \cos \theta \quad y = r \sin \theta$$

Comment: Why do you say $r=3/\cos\theta$ "makes no sense?"

Comment: I know the formulas, but what do I plug in the theta part?

Comment: If I will divide it by 3, I'll only get r but not the theta part, leaving me no clue about its graph.

Comment: Ah, that's different from "not making sense." "I can't figure out what to do next" is not usually written in English as "It does not making sense." "Not making sense" is reserved for things which are illogical, not things we don't understand or can't figure out.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that:

- $x = r \cos \theta$
- $y = r \sin \theta$

Thus, your equation is simply $x = 3$, a simple [vertical line](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r%20cos%20theta%20=%203).

Comment: Holy crap it was that simple. Thanks!